# Trying to have Excel VBA return a 0 when dividing

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to get Excel VBA to return a number 0 in Cell D16(Conversion Rate) if cell D7 (Submissions) is a zero when dividing cell D13 (Hires) / D7 (Submissions). We sometimes don't have submissions but have hires from previous submissions (that we aren't allowed to record as a submission twice). The user clicks on a convert button to get the conversion rate, but the user keeps getting a Run-time error '11': Division by zero. We know that we have to occasionally put a zero in cell D7, but the user can't access the conversion rate box to manually type in the zero and can't leave D7 blank when submitting the form.

My current code for the division is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Range("D16") = Range("D13") / Range("D7")
End Sub
```

Can anyone help?

[User Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ARNA.png)

[With Zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur1ha.png)

Comment: Try checking `If Range("D7").Value = 0` first?

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new at VBA. I tried the If then Statement but it returns the same run-time error

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with your attempt?

Comment: And Thank you BigBen for such a quick response to my question

Comment: I can change the code you see but am unable to edit on the front end

Comment: I may be misunderstanding how you are using your "If" statement you asked me to use in your first comment. Are you able to show it in the code I sent originally? If not, I understand.

Comment: I will post that portion form so you can get a better understanding

Answer (score 1):

You can better solve this in the cell and not by code like:

```
=if (D7 = 0, 0, D13/D7)
```

We first check if D7 = zero and if so the cell gets filled wiht zero else with your formula.

if you want to do it in code:

```
if Range("D7").value = 0 or IsEmpty(Range("D7").value) then
    Range("D16").value = 0
else
    Range("D16").value = Range("D13").value / Range("D7").value
end if
```

Comment: It worked! You are an absolute genius!! Thank you so much...